# finding elements from list with different format of strings

Tags: string, python-2.7, list

I have a large list with elements as:

```
#1
#10
(on
)
0.0574
122-124
122A
Cat
Dog
elephant
elephant12
elephant-1
```

I want to search and be able to find only the following:

```
Cat
Dog
elephant
elephant12
elephant-1
```

i.e. elements which have an English alphabet at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension:

```
import string

result = [item for item in my_list if item[0] in string.ascii_letters]
```

As @Jon commented, check if a character is a letter can simply be:

```
result = [item for item in my_list if item[0].isalpha()]
```

The above works when all items are string, and you expect items with leading English character. Change the `if` part as needed or even write a function if it is too complex.

If you are looking for memory-optimized version, consider `generator`.

Comment: You know that `return =` is going to throw a syntaxerror?

Comment: @JonClements Sorry for my typo, it should be `result`.

Comment: Depending on how strictly the ascii requirement is - using `if item[0].isalpha()` might do it and will be quicker

Answer (score -1):

You could work with a list of animals.
for example:

```
list=["cat","dog","elephant","fish","bird", "snake"]
```

then search for any of those strings in your input
I know there are better methods but I would do it with

```
def search(input):
  for item in list:
    if item in input:
      result.append(item)
  return result
```

Then you would add case ignorance precisions.
If you want the number associated with your animal name, you'll need to append the input. In this case, iterate your input.

Of course your list could take the dimension of a database if you need, for example to search for all possible existing word.